# How to sort ArrayList<String> containing elements of ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> that has been sorted by a comparator?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I am getting some data via JSON which I store in a **Hashmap  map** e.g. **map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getString("title"))** and then add the map to an **ArrayList> bookList**. This is displayed in a list view with bookList as source for the adapter. Additionally I also store all the book info (title, author, published date) of the map in **Arraylist arrTitles, arrAuthors, arrDates** as I need to pass these values to my next activity. My problem is when I use a comparator to sort the bookList on basis of titles then the bookList gets sorted just fine. I however want to sort my arrTitles, arrAuthors and arrDates as per the new sorting of the bookList so that my arrTitles.getItem(position) sends the correct value to the next activity. Any idea how I can do this? Below are the hashmap, arraylist, onItemClick & comparator code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < json.Length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, json.getString("id"));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, json.getString("title"));
        map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, json.getString("author"));
        map.put(KEY_DATE, json.getString("date"));
        arrTitles.add(json.getString("title");
        arrAuthors.add(json.getString("author");
        arrDates.add(json.getString("date");
        //add map to ArrayList
        booksList.add(map);
}

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        Collections.sort(booksList, mapComparator);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, booksList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, editList.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", arrTitles.getItem(position));
        intent.putExtra("date", arrDates.getItem(position));
        startActivity(intent);


        }
    }); 
 } 

       public Comparator<Map<String, String>> mapComparator = new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
       public int compare(Map<String, String> m1, Map<String, String> m2) {
       return m1.get(KEY_TITLE).compareTo(m2.get(KEY_TITLE));
    }
};
```

Comment: It's hard to tell the context as you've posted code from half way through a method. Is this code in a loop? It's not clear how we'll end up with multiple items, especially as you're starting a new activity immediately after adding to the lists. Also, is there any good reason for using a map rather than creating a `Book` class with a `title` property etc? The latter would be cleaner in general, IMO.

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes the booksList gets updated in a loop. Have updated my code to reflect the same.

Comment: And are the collections empty before the loop?

Comment: Yes the collections are empty before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, with the new code it seems reasonably simple: just create the individual lists *after* you've sorted the list of maps:

```
// This loop looks wrong at the moment - you're not using i
for (int i = 0; i < json.Length(); i++) {
     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
     map.put(KEY_ID, json.getString("id"));
     map.put(KEY_TITLE, json.getString("title"));
     map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, json.getString("author"));
     map.put(KEY_DATE, json.getString("date"));
     booksList.add(map);
}

for (Map<String, String> map : booksList) {
     arrTitles.add(map.get(KEY_TITLE));
     arrAuthors.add(map.get(KEY_AUTHOR));
     arrDates.add(map.get(KEY_DATE));
}
```

Note that I would still strongly recommend creating a `Book` class to store the data in, instead of using a `Map<String, String>` with fixed keys. It'll be a lot simpler to work with elsewhere in the code, I suspect.

Comment: Thanks, let me give a go to creating the Book class.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct only. You have to format as per requirement. you getting  arrTitles, arrAuthors and arrDates from the json object. in my understand you have to get the data after shot the map.
Below is some modify code. have look on this

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.Length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, json.getString("id"));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, json.getString("title"));
            map.put(KEY_AUTHOR, json.getString("author"));
            map.put(KEY_DATE, json.getString("date"));

            //add map to ArrayList
            booksList.add(map);
    }





            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            Collections.sort(booksList, mapComparator);
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, booksList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (Map<String, String> map : booksList) {
                arrTitles.add(json.getString("title");
                arrAuthors.add(json.getString("author");
                arrDates.add(json.getString("date");
        }

            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, editList.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", arrTitles.getItem(position));
            intent.putExtra("date", arrDates.getItem(position));
            startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The map inside the booklist has all the required details, so why dont you get the map object for that particular listitem from the adapter and get the details from the map.

Answer (score 0):

@gvmani: I think you are referring to an implementation similar to the one I have done below:-

```
            HashMap <String,String> mapBook = booksList.get(position);
            String strTitle = mapBook.get(KEY_TITLE);
            String strAuthor = mapBook.get(KEY_AUTHOR);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListView.this,editList.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", strTitle);
            intent.putExtra("author", strAuthor);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: something on similar lines. I guess it will be better to use your adapter to return the map for the particular position.